# Parametric Surfaces Appearing completely different in graphing software than in original paper

Tags: curves, polar-coordinates, surfaces, parametric, spherical-coordinates

I tried to plot the parametric surfaces from [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Michael-Cortie/publication/238757952_Models_for_mollusc_shell_shape/links/547b92170cf2a961e489c4ad/Models-for-mollusc-shell-shape.pdf) to try to play around with the variables and potentially adapt it for other purposes. However I attempted to plot the surfaces in both Geogebra and Math3D with the parameters from the original paper, to minimal success. I have made sure to convert the appropriate values to radians, however the shapes are still completely wrong. I am not sure if I am misinterpreting the values or if there is a mistake in the equations and functions.

Geogebra: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/t9smcgaq

Math3D: https://www.math3d.org/LqpWldNxh

The parameters I used are the ones for the nautilus.

The parametric equation in question is:
$$
\begin{cases} 
x = \bigl( A\sin(\beta) 
+ g(s)\cos(s+\phi)\cos(\theta+\Omega) 
- g(s)\sin(\mu)\sin(s+\phi)\sin(\theta) \bigr) \, e^{\theta\cot(\alpha)} \\[2pt]
y = \bigl( -A\sin(\beta) 
- g(s)\cos(s+\phi)\sin(\theta+\Omega) 
- g(s)\sin(\mu)\sin(s+\phi)\cos(\theta) \bigr) \, 
e^{\theta\cot(\alpha)} \\[2pt]
z = \bigl( -A\cos(\beta) 
+ g(s)\sin(s+\phi)\cos(\mu) \bigr) \, e^{\theta\cot(\alpha)}
\end{cases}
$$
for
$\theta\in (\theta_{\mathrm{start}},\theta_{\mathrm{end}})$ and $s\in (s_{\min},s_{\max})$
and
$$
g(s) = \bigl( a^{-2}\cos^2(s) + b^{-2}\sin^2(s) \bigr)^{-1/2}
$$

The meanings of the variables are lined out in [the paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Michael-Cortie/publication/238757952_Models_for_mollusc_shell_shape/links/547b92170cf2a961e489c4ad/Models-for-mollusc-shell-shape.pdf).

Comment: I played with the parameter ranges, and the $-\infty$ starting point for $\theta$ seems to be an issue. Geogebra doesn't draw anything when given $-\infty$ as lower bound, but any other number doesn't draw the correct shape.

Comment: The issue was that, and you (and I until now) missed the erratum. You should add a $\cos(\theta)$ factor to the $A\sin(\beta)$ term in equation (9) (the parametric equation for x) and a $\sin(\theta)$ factor to the $A\sin(\beta)$ term in equation (10) (the parametric equation for y). https://www.math3d.org/Xt6fThSap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you had was that the paper has an error in equations (9) and (10). The errata states that you need to add a $\cos(\theta)$ after the $A\cos(\beta)$ in (9) and a $\sin(\theta)$ after the $A\cos(\beta)$ in (10).

Your parametric equations then become:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{cases}
x&=&\big(A\sin(\beta)\cos(\theta)+g(s)cos(s+\phi)cos(\theta+\Omega)-g(s)sin(\mu)sin(s+\phi)sin(\theta)\big)e^{\theta\cot(\alpha)}\\
y&=&\big(-A\sin(\beta)\sin(\theta)+g(s)cos(s+\phi)sin(\theta+\Omega)-g(s)sin(\mu)sin(s+\phi)cos(\theta)\big)e^{\theta\cot(\alpha)}\\
z&=&\big(-A\cos(\beta)+g(s)\sin(s+\phi)\cos(\mu)\big)e^{\theta\cot(\alpha)}
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I did that and changed your constants to exactly the constants in Table 1 for nautilus. I had to play around with $\theta_{start}$, since $-\infty$ does not work on the math3d or geogebra plotter.

This is what I finally came up with: https://www.math3d.org/maV8BHWE2. Not too bad.

Comment: Thanks! I feel really dumb for not noticing that, I should have been more observant!